# Extract first date from text in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using following regex to find first date in a each line.

```
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4}
```

This is working but it is matching all the dates. But, I just need the first date "Feb 19 22:25:19 2018" in each line.

Sample text file

```
Mon Feb 19 22:25:19 2018 ABC.ls:9999: some text here, Mon Feb 19 22:25:19 2017\n
Mon Feb 19 22:25:20 2018 ABC.ls:9999: some text here\n
Mon Feb 19 22:25:20 2018 ABC.ls:9999: some text here, () with some more text\n
```

TIA

Comment: Please post the code you are using. The regex is fine, but how are you processing the text? Is it read from a file?

Comment: If regex is working good, use `re.search` to find only the first occurance in the string.

Comment: Updated Solution:
   
 `re = r"(?m)^.*?((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s[0-9\s]\d{1}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4})"
    regex_pattern = re.compile(reg)
    with gzip.open(path, 'rt') as src:
        log_timestamps = re.findall(regex_pattern, src.read())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

- read the file line by line
- use `re.search` to find the first match on a line
- if there is a match (and only then) grab the match group #0.

Something like

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4}')
res = []
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = rx.search(line)
        if m:
            res.append(m.group())
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rwXo2a):

```
import re

file = """Mon Feb 19 22:25:19 2018 ABC.ls:9999: some text here, Mon Feb 19 22:25:19 2017
Mon Feb 19 22:25:20 2018 ABC.ls:9999: some text here
Mon Feb 19 22:25:20 2018 ABC.ls:9999: some text here, () with some more text"""

rx = re.compile(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4}')
res = []
for s in file.splitlines():
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m:
        res.append(m.group())

print(res)
# => ['Feb 19 22:25:19 2018', 'Feb 19 22:25:20 2018', 'Feb 19 22:25:20 2018']
```

Since you want to read the whole file into the memory and grab all the necessary matches with a single call to `re.findall`, you may use

```
re.findall(r'(?m)^.*?((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d{4})', file_contents)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVkQb3/2)

The regex is of the `(?m)^.*?(...)` form, that matches

- `(?m)` - `re.M` / `re.MULTILINE` mode is on to make `^` match the start of a line
- `^` - the start of a line
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(...)` - a capturing group that will capture your datetime pattern, and `re.findall` only returns captured texts if the capturing group(s) is defined in the pattern.

Comment: @ Wiktor , nice solution, my +1

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for the solution. But I don't want to read line by line as this regex needs to work on logs. I want to apply regex in re.findall function

Comment: @Lufy That is why I asked how you process data. I will update with `re.findall(r'(?m)^.*?(your_pattern)', s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Really appreciate your quick response. Works like a charm. Thanks for the explanation as well!!!